# Does DevForce use the same transaction for validation and the save

Tags: validation, transactions, devforce

I can't seem to find this on their site or here.  I'm hoping the answer is YES.  Specifically I want to write a Verifier to check for unique key violations (I know I will have to raise the isolation level to Serializable).  This won't work unless the Verifier runs in the same transaction as the Save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevForce does not use the same transaction for validation and save processing.  Within the context of an EntityServerSaveInterceptor, authorization and validation are performed and then a TransactionScope is opened when doing the actual save.  If you do a query within a verifier it will use a separate TransactionScope.

You can work around this behavior with a little extra work in your custom EntityServerSaveInterceptor.  Override the ValidateSave function to bypass validation, then override the ExecuteSave method to open a TransactionScope and then do your validation logic before calling the base save logic.  The TransactionScope opened by DF during the save will enlist in your TransactionScope.  Something like this:

```
public class EntityServerSaveManager : EntityServerSaveInterceptor {

  protected override bool ValidateSave() {
    // will do validation later
    return true;
  }

  protected override bool ExecuteSave() {
    using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, this.SaveOptions.TransactionSettings.ToTransactionOptions())) {
      // Do validation logic now
      ...

      // Now do save
      base.ExecuteSave();
      ts.Complete();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So as part of 'Do validation logic now', after doing my custom validation, I would call base.ValidateSave()?  If I write a UniqueVerifier, would the 'Do validation logic now' be just a call to base.ValidateSave()?

Comment: Your instance verifiers will be called automatically by base.ValidateSave, so you could just call base.ValidateSave within your TransactionScope.

Comment: When I try this, I get the following exception: The transaction specified for TransactionScope has a different IsolationLevel than the value requested for the scope.  How to I set the DefaultSaveOptions for ALL entity managers on both the client and server.  I am using Cocktail if that matters.